# Why am I unable to install the Nvidia 96 driver?

Tags: 11.04, drivers, nvidia, package-management

I have a old Nvidia card that needs the nvidia 96 driver to enable all the fancy compiz effects (the noveau free driver doesn't work). I tried installing it with Ubuntu Software Center but it said that it had dependency problems.

Comment: did you try Additional Drivers under the System>Administration menu?

Comment: This is a bug in Natty right now: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-96/+bug/741930

Comment: Great, made it an answer, so the workaround doesn't get lost in the comment section. :)

Comment: @htorque SWEET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long this is [an open bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-96/+bug/741930), you can try the open-source driver Nouveau. To enable the experimental 3D support for this driver, you need to install the package `libgl1-mesa-dri-experimental`.

Although it says experimental and is still unsupported by upstream developers, that driver works pretty well on a lot of Nvidia cards.

Comment: Sadly, as long as we rely on proprietary hardware, we're always going to run into issues like this, as we are at the mercy of the discretion of the vendors. Since NVIDIA are the only ones who have access to their proprietary drivers' source code, only NVIDIA can provide a solution to this problem.

As of today, the latest "96" driver only supports X.org 1.9. http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-96.43.19-driver.html Until/unless NVIDIA decides it's worth their time to release an updated "96" driver, the only thing we can do is sit and wait.