# Removing nvidia drivers without killing kubuntu-desktop (Kubuntu 12.04)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, cuda

I am trying to install CUDA drivers on kubuntu 12.04, but in order to do so I need to remove nvidia drivers (which come in with the distro). The problem I have is that while doing so it also removes kubuntu-desktop, which is disasterous (though cuda installs ok). I had the same problem when trying Linux Mint 13 KDE.

I followed the link here:
http://sn0v.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/installing-cuda-on-ubuntu-12-04/ 
and noticed that some people have come across this problem as well, but no solution has been found yet - except for not installing the cuda, lol.

I also tried this:

> sudo apt-get purge nvidia-common

only to get the same warning of being about to remove the desktop:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
    kubuntu-desktop nvidia-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 435 not upgraded.
After this operation, 197 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
```

My question is - can you remove the nvidia drivers in a way that does not remove kubuntu-desktop (or ubuntu-desktop) at the same time? 
Or do I have to go with killing the desktop and then install the it again after cuda is installed? Wouldn't it affect other apps, which depend on kubuntu-desktop?

I need CUDA for my CG work and so any help would be really welcome, thanks!

Comment: Why dont you remove it from the Jockey? which is basically the additional drivers ?

Comment: Thanks for reply; I haven't activated any of the drivers from the Additional Drivers yet (I am working on a fresh kubuntu install) and there seems to be no way to remove them from this list (that I know of) - is that what you meant?

Comment: I installed CUDA and the NVIDIA drivers on Kubuntu 12.04 and didn't have any issues. I think I just installed the new drivers without uninstalling anything, and X was automatically reconfigured to use the new drivers.

Comment: To avoid having the drivers that come with Kubuntu be installed, I guess you could start the install without an NVIDIA graphics card in the machine. Then install CUDA, then add the graphics card.

Comment: @Phil_thy Yea That is what I meant. I think this is what you are looking for: http://askubuntu.com/questions/112302/how-do-i-disable-the-nouveau-kernel-driver Look at the 1st solution :)

Comment: Finally I managed to sort it out, by following this link: http://chrislaidler.blogspot.com/2012/05/cuda-429-and-kubuntu-1204.html
It appears the blacklist of drivers suggested in here http://sn0v.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/installing-cuda-on-ubuntu-12-04/ 
was not good (incomplete) for kubuntu.  
Also, I used the rhe15.5 version of the nvidia drivers, as suggested in the link.

Comment: @Roger Dahl: Thanks for your tips; you probably used different drivers than I did, which I think was the problem (I had trouble with the conflicting Nouveau Kernel from the very start). I would have probably resorted to the graphic card removal trick in the end, if was unsuccessful.

Comment: @Suhaib: thanks for your help, I think the link you gave me would be also a good solution - as mentioned, the blacklist I created before was incomplete and did not work, here is presented the appropriate one, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following this link helped:

http://chrislaidler.blogspot.com/2012/05/cuda-429-and-kubuntu-1204.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question (as the one who posted the question, you probably know it does), [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
    kubuntu-desktop nvidia-common
```

`kubuntu-desktop` is a meta-package. I.e. it's a virtual package, which has other packages as dependencies. Removing this package doesn't remove the packages which depend on it.

So, the answer is: don't worry that `kubuntu-desktop` package is removed.