# Ubuntu 19.04 not booting after change of graphic card

Tags: boot, nvidia, 19.04, amd-graphics

I had an old AMD Radeon Graphics card (really old, it is of AMD ATI series), on which I ran 19.04. It was working perfectly fine, until I changed the graphics card.

I now inserted an Nvidia GeForce 210, tried to boot Ubuntu.
The loading dots come, color of dots change till last dot, it stops. I found an unusual thing happening. A command line appeared out of nowhere and many commands were running. Something like Starting VPN servers..starting mysqld..starting gnome display manager etc.

Finally, the command scroll came to a stop, stuck at starting BP Filter.
Next an error comes stating that Cannot run ubuntu on this graphics card, failed to load gnome display manager.

Nothing happens after that, no commands work. Even the basic commands like `ls`, `cd`, `pwd` dont work. I dont know how this is connected to change of graphic card.
Any idea what happened? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried starting ubuntu in safe mod ? https://askubuntu.com/a/172346/997445 also here is a similar question https://askubuntu.com/questions/527638/how-to-install-drivers-for-nvidia-gt210