# Booting Problem - Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.01 LTS

Tags: boot, gnome

So, I mounted Kali Linux Light iso image on my usb stick and ran it Live. Eveything was fine. When I finished, I shut down the Kali and unplugged my usb. Then I turned back on my PC and my screen started flashing before login screen.
I'm getting this message:

```
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1: clean 221608/30269440 files, 4431756/121048320 blocks
[  OK  ] Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
[  OK  ] Created slice User Slice for gdm.
         Starting User Manager for UID 121...
[  OK  ] Started Session c1 of user gdm.
[  OK  ] Started User Manager for UID 121.
         Stopping User Manager for UID 121...
_
```

I'm not sure if this is connected somehow.

I tried this (but it didn't help):

1. Checked BIOS settings
2. Reinstalled GRUB using my installation USB (I ran a live version with it, here's the report - http://paste2.org/78CUHf9H )
3. Scanned for issues in recovery mode

I can hit CTRL+ALT+F1 while my screen is flashing, but every 4 seconds my monitor flashes again with this error message ^^ so I need to hit those buttons again to access the terminal again, it's really annoying.

Comment: Do you have NVIDIA/AMD graphics?

Comment: CPU: AMD Phenom II X4 Quad Core 3,40GHz
GPU: ASUS Nvidia GeForce GTX650 1GB

Comment: Did you install the proprietary driver for the NVIDIA card?

Comment: Yes, it was working fine. I had some trouble at first place because I needed to blacklist nouveau, but I did that right and it installed correctly.

Comment: OK. It's possible either Xorg got messed up or the NVIDIA driver. Since I don't know which version of the NVIDIA driver you installed, or how you did it, I can't really tell you how to purge it, but get into recovery, uninstall the video driver, and purge/reinstall `apt-get purge xserver-xorg`.

Comment: I've downloaded them from here: http://www.geforce.com/drivers and I think it was this version 367.44. 
When I downloaded .run file on my pc, I opened a terminal and started it with # sudo ./nvidia-driver-blah-blah-version.run and I got an error saying that I need to disable nouveau, so I did something weird. I created a nvidia file which contains blacklist scripts for nouveau inside. Like mentioned here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/112302/how-do-i-disable-the-nouveau-kernel-driver . 
So, I will try your method in the next 5 minutes and see what happens.

Comment: You may want to try following this in Recovery: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics/760935#760935. The `.run` files never work well.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot, the problem was really there!
After reinstalling the nvidia drivers, xorg and gnome desktop everything works like a charm! :)

Comment: Great! I'll put it up as an answer then.

Answer (score 13):

I would normally refer you to [my Q&A on NVIDIA issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics/760935#760935), but that involves using TTYs, which won't work for you, at least right away.

Boot into Recovery Mode, drop to a root shell, and follow the steps below:

1. Run `mount -o rw,remount /` to mount the drive in Read-Write mode.
2. Run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` to purge the NVIDIA driver.

   - You may also need to purge `xserver-xorg` and reinstall it, which will require you to enable networking in Recovery.
3. Reboot. You may have to add the `nouveau.modeset=0` flag in GRUB to boot properly (Check my Q&A for specifics).

You should be past the screen flicker and be at your desktop.

4. Now reinstall the NVIDIA drivers the proper way:

   - `sudo apt-get install nvidia-367` (or `340`, `352`, `364`, `370`, whichever works).
5. Reboot again.

You should be up and running: good as before. I don't see how Kali could have done this, but if you messed around with your filesystem, then it's definitely possible.

Comment: I keep re-running into this issue on Step 4. Everytime I am installing nvidia drivers via the commandline. But all of them seem to cause this issue?

Comment: It works for me, but I'm curious de know why 90% of my Ubuntu issues come from Nvidia? How can I avoid this for future upgrade?

Comment: Note: the newest Nvidia drivers are now under the name `nvidia-driver-XXX`, where "XXX" is the driver version. So if you're upgrading your driver to 430, then it would be `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. When examining the logs in /var/log it was kindof obvious, that the issue was because of gdm3. Since lighdm never works for me I had to find a completely different display manager. It worked for me with SLiM, bit i did not try any other dm yet. I'm probably just going to install some flat theme for it and keep it.

https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Displaymanager/

```
sudo apt-get install slim
```

i managed to get into tty2 (Strg+Alt+F2) and do this. But if this doesn't work for you, you can also enter a console in the advanced boot options on startup.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

(Nvidia & Ubuntu 16.10)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, SLiM did not help at all, so I reverted everything like this:

1. Boot from live CD
2. Mount my Harddisk with chroot as described here under Update Failure: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery
   including writing the resolv.conf entry
3. Navigated to my Downloads folder where the Nvidia driver was and did an uninstall with: cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-0-local_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb --uninstall
4. Deleted /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf and regenerate kernel:
   sudo update-initramfs -u
5. Edit grub to boot into text console
6. Reboot into harddrive
7. login to command line
8. sudo apt-get install nvidia
9. reboot
10. Finally back in the graphical system, took the whole night, hope this helps someone doing the same s**t.