# Booting issue on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using GNOME 3

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, gnome, gdm

So, I booted up Ubuntu, and for some reason, the display was turning on and off erratically, and my computer was making small whining noises whenever the display dimmed. I had to force shut down my computer, but a reboot didn't fix it. The message that continuously flashed up on the screen for moments was:

```
250GB_SSD: recovering journal
250GB_SSD: clean, 578229/14745600 files, 46225615/58964224 blocks
[  OK  ] Created slice User Slice of gdm.
Starting User Manager for UID 124...
[  OK  ] Started Session c1 of user gdm.
[  OK  ] Started User Manager for UID 124.
Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
[  OK  ] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Stopping User Manager for UID 124...
[  OK  ] Stopped User Manager for UID 124.
_
```

Every time I rebooted, I believe the same sort of message came up.
Eventually, I went into Recovery Mode and tried some things. I've looked at many others who have also had this problem, and apparently it can be traced back to gdm and NVIDIA drivers (seeing I run both gdm and a NVIDIA driver). I have looked at things such as this: [Booting Problem - Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.01 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826622/booting-problem-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-01-lts). The things I'm seeing are similar to this. However, for some reason I can't enable networking within Recovery Mode. This is because

```
gdm: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory
```

Because of this I cannot download any packages using `apt-get`.
I have also gone `sudo apt-get purge xserver.xorg` in an attempt to reinstall it, but, seeing I cannot download new packages, this is now gone (until I manage to enable networking).

So, now, I am completely at a loss at what to do. I cannot remember myself messing with the file system last time I've been on it, I don't think I did.

Also, I'm a Linux noob, I've only switched to it in August, which gives me about 2 months of experience :B sorry.

I'll appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the xserver.xorg goes corrupt so I purge, then reinstall it, to solve the network requirement I used [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1886947) (my etc0 doesn’t resolve dns names).

My steps:

Enter grub (hold shift key at boot)
Enter recovery mode (safe mode)
Chose Network (enable networking)
root (drop to root shell)

sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf (this create the file)
add these two lines to the file:

nameserver 192.168.1.1

nameserver 8.8.8.8

execute:

apt-get remove --auto-remove xserver.xorg

apt-get install xserver.xorg
reboot