# Ubuntu 17.10 boots forever after update. Is it normal?

Tags: boot, 17.10, update-manager, reboot, 18.04

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10. My Update Manager installed some updates (maybe for 18.04) and asked for a reboot, which I did. Now my laptop has been booting for about two hours. Is this normal? If not, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Press esc when seeing the boot animation. You should be able to see some messages. Also try ctrl+alt+F1 through F7 if you can get to a terminal.

Comment: @AndreasHartmann The messages move up and down really fast, but from as far as I can see, it says "Started User Manager ... UID 121" then "Stopped User Manager ... UID 121"

Comment: @AndreasHartmann It also says "A start job is running for hold until boot finishes up" with no time limit

Comment: Can you reach a terminal with ctrl+alt+F1 through F7?

Comment: Do you happen to have an nvidia card?

Comment: @AndreasHartmann I do. After receiving "start job" message I googled it and found https://askubuntu.com/questions/760825/cannot-boot-system-due-to-start-job-running-for-hold and ran only the 1st two remove commands and the last isntall command. I do not yet understand what really happened, but you and it helped. Thanks alot! Also, if you could be so kind as to explain what happened back there, it would help a bunch! :)

Comment: Plymouth has been problematic for a while. I figured it might be related to an error during installation of nvidia drivers and would have suggested you follow these steps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/826622/booting-problem-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-01-lts?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @AndreasHartmann Thanks! Is this due to happen whenever I wish to upgrade to 18.04?

Comment: Probably not - it's some unusual and untested constellation that occurred with your particular system. I myself have been able to upgrade several machines without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got bricked yesterday when my HWE kernel updated to 4.13.0-39. It also looked like it was just stuck. It went through a number of various system status lines about two thirds down my screen and then nothing. It looked like it was just going to boot forever. Not so. The system was actually done loading, it was simply unable to start the GUI. When you get to the point where the system appears to be stuck in a 'boot loop', try this key combo to get the text-based login prompt: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. I know that there may be more than one combination and if there are additional combinations that people know about, please comment. On my laptop it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

I have a pet supercomputer for scientific computing. There appears to be some kind of a problem with the `linux-headers` package in that kernel. I have the 1070 video card. I was able to recover from this minor disaster. See if you have the same problem. Try this (if you have this particular kernel, the problem also exists in the `-38`):

```
uname -a
```

if the answer is a `-38` or `-39` kernel, then you have a problem. If you have the `-38` kernel, change the line below accordingly of course.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.13.0-39-generic
```

If your machine decides to do an installation, then you have a problem. Good, let it install. After that:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-396
```

Reboot and your system should come back to life. Mine did.

Comment: It only appears like it boots forever. It's actually done, just can't bring up the GUI. If the user tries the magic key to switch to the text prompt either CTRL-ALT-F1 or CTRL-ALT-F7, they will see that the system is actually up. Been there, sat through that.