# Ubuntu 18.04 3D acceleration on VirtualBox

Tags: nvidia, graphics, virtualbox, xorg, ubuntu-gnome

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on VirtualBox and then set the 3D acceleration ON and when I try to start it, it shows and stays like this:

[image: Screenshot]

It worked fine with Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.10 but doesn't work with 18.04. I have Windows 10, Nvidia GPU, latest Virtualbox and drivers. I'm using GNOME with Xorg.

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: I made some progress with lightdm from these posts: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027725/ubuntu-17-10-boots-forever-after-update-is-it-normal?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa  https://askubuntu.com/questions/760825/cannot-boot-system-due-to-start-job-running-for-hold I could get to a login screen with lightdm, but not log in

Comment: same issue here, windows 7 host, vbox 5.2.10

Answer (score 1):

Using the .iso provided in the Ubuntu repository (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/virtualbox-guest-additions-iso/download) resolved this issue for me on Virtualbox 5.2.8. On Windows just download and extract the .iso using 7zip or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of VirtualBox you're running. Upgrading to the latest version (5.2.10) of VirtualBox as well as the guest additions package resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I thought I had the latest version because when I checked for new updates it said I was running the latest version. I'll try the new version

Comment: Ok, so seems like the reason why it works on VB 5.2.10 is because there is no 3D acceleration happening in Ubuntu (even though it's enabled on the VM). So this resolved my problem only to the same extent as would disabling 3D acceleration.

Comment: I'm using v5.2.10 with Ubuntu 16.04 as host and 18.04 as guest. I still see the option to enable 3D support for the guest which keeps causing the same problem. Upgrading didn't solve anything but disabling 3D support did

Comment: 5.2.10, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

see also 
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=87919

> ... or to choose Gnome Classic from the login cog. That works too.
>
> Worth reading: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/X11Guest3D

Comment: so, what is the solution?

Comment: VirtualBpx 5.2.12 has fixed the issue

Comment: Upgrading to 5.2.12 Did not fix for me... it is still slow and when I call `glxgears' it hangs the interface while the gears keep spinning.