# Frozen login screen

Tags: login-screen

I recently tried to remove a package ("bumblebee"), running "apt remove" from my computer running Ubuntu 18.04. Unfortunately, the remove processed stucked at a certain percent, so I had to kill the process.
At this point, my computer was still running fine from what I could tell.

Then I rebooted it, and now I am not able to login anymore : the screen is totally frozen, mouse and keyboard are not responding.

I tried to run an older Ubuntu version from grub. I also tried to repair the package with the recovery mode.
After a few research on the internet, a few post pointed out that it might be caused by Nvidia drivers which I thought not impossible since the issue was caused by bumblebee removal. So I removed all Nvidia drivers using "apt-get purge nvidia-*" from root shell , and also removed totally "bumblebee" using the same process , but it didn't fix my issue.

Does someone has an idea?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by following this answer : https://askubuntu.com/a/826641/1045850

I had already purged the nvidia drivers, but it seems that purge and then reinstall xserver-xorg did the trick.