# Boot problem after hanging and manual power off ( Stopping User Manager for UID 121... )

Tags: boot, virtualbox

My Ubuntu stalled while running Android's VirtualBox version, so I powered off the system.

But after reset it stopped during this line:

Stopping User Manager for UID 121... _

So i googled it and have read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826622/booting-problem-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-01-lts) question and tried these steps:

> Boot into Recovery Mode, drop to a root shell, and follow the steps
>
> below:
>  
> Run mount -o rw,remount / to mount the drive in Read-Write
> mode.Run sudo apt-get purge nvidia-* to purge the NVIDIA driver.You
> may also need to purge xserver-xorg and reinstall it, which will
>  require you to enable networking in Recovery.Reboot. You may have to
> add the nouveau.modeset=0 flag in GRUB to boot properly (Check my Q&A
> for specifics).
>  
> You should be past the screen flicker and be at your desktop.

But in doing this step:

> Now reinstall the NVIDIA drivers the proper way:sudo apt-get install
>  nvidia-367 (or 340, 352, 364, 370, whichever works).Reboot again.

I found i have not internet, and my WiFi is not in `ifconfig` list!!!

By running :

`Iw wlp2s0 scan`

I get :

`N180211 not found`

I also search for it and not understand why WiFi gone off.

Now i thinking to use live USB of ubuntu to download **NVIDIA** and **xserver-xorg** and the install the by dpkg command during tty2.

**Update :**

in Ubuntu live i have this settings :

[image]

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:129 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 920MX]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

and

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -c display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:129 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 920MX]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

and :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$  cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

please consider the above three output has token form Ubuntu live flash system.

What do you suggest and what do you think about reason of this failure?

Also do you think it must be reported by me in ubuntu site, or it will be done automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with booting the system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163516/problems-with-booting-the-system)

Comment: Did you purge `xserver-xorg`? If No, then the answer above should work for you. If Yes, then you need to boot with a live cd or USB and re-install `xserver-xorg`

Comment: @Raffa , yes uninstall it, now how i could reinstall it from live USB Ubuntu, the main question is about doing this. my WiFi setting don't work at main Ubuntu but working here i live CD.

Answer (score 1):

To fix from a live USB, connect to Internet from the live system and open a terminal then follow these steps:

Run:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

And identify your root partition. It could be something like `/dev/sda1` then mount it to `/mnt` like so:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/
```

Then run:

```
sudo mount --bind /proc/ /mnt/proc/
```

Then run:

```
sudo mount --bind /sys/ /mnt/sys/
```

Then run:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev/ /mnt/dev/
```

Then run:

```
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
```

Then run:

```
sudo chroot /mnt/
```

Now you are in your original system on the hard disk. Update APT first like so:

```
apt update
```

Then install `xserver-xorg` like so:

```
apt install xserver-xorg
```

Then run:

```
apt purge nvidia-*
```

Then run:

```
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

When finished run:

```
exit
```

Then run:

```
sudo umount /mnt/dev/
```

Then run:

```
sudo umount /mnt/sys/
```

Then run:

```
sudo umount /mnt/proc/
```

Then run:

```
sudo umount /mnt/
```

Then reboot to your original system, it should be fixed

Comment: Thanks@Raffa, i was watching the west world S03-07 and now i am thinking how is that you are so professional, you surprised me, thanks for giving your time to me.

Comment: @modern : ) You are most welcome. Have you fixed it? or you need more help?

Comment: It is showing the login screen page know but after inserting the pass return to itself, which i have seen it before which is because of nvidia driver mismatch and i hope to solve this part as i did before but, still dont have wifi internet.

Comment: @modern Yes, it is NVIDIA. Just go to recovery mode and follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163539/968501) ... No more and No less : ) and you should be able to login and if you have to install NVIDIA drivers from the additional drivers tab in Software & Updates in the GUI after login and keep in mind that NVIDIA drivers do not always work as expected and you might be better running the open source Xorg driver.