# Wifi driver is lost after a manual power off

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

My Ubuntu stalled while running Android's VirtualBox version, so I powered off the system.

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232148/boot-problem-after-hanging-and-manual-power-off-stopping-user-manager-for-uid/1232168?noredirect=1#comment2074026_1232168) previous question, now ti could login to Ubuntu OS, but the problem with WiFi driver acquired and when i run `ifconfig` it down show the WiFi data,

so i tried to install WiFi driver from live USB Ubuntu by this codes:

```
sudo apt remove broadcom-sta-dkms bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo add-apt-repository restricted
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
sudo apt autoremove
```

and by the live USB environment it showing it is installed :

```
root@ubuntu:/# ifconfig
enp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether c8:5b:76:8b:3e:ae  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4589  bytes 386757 (386.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4589  bytes 386757 (386.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::1153:1820:27de:5a87  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c8:3d:d4:3c:23:63  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 32549  bytes 35889892 (35.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 25157  bytes 3314860 (3.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

now it showing the WiFi via Ubuntu live CD and `sudo chroot /mnt/` like this:

```
root@ubuntu:/# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 920MX] (rev a2)
root@ubuntu:/# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"TP-LINK_4AD2"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.447 GHz  Access Point: D4:6E:0E:45:4A:D2   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:303   Missed beacon:0

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.
```

but don't showing this setting via the main Ubuntu in my PC, and can not connect to internet there?

the version of main Ubuntu get form live USB is like this:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$  cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

**Update:**
Also get this output via live USB Ubuntu version:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/modprobe.d# sudo ifup wlp2s0
Unknown interface wlp2s0

root@ubuntu:/etc/modprobe.d# sudo modprobe rtl8821ae
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8821ae not found in directory /lib/modules/5.0.0-23-generic
```

And based of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333424/how-can-i-check-the-information-of-currently-installed-wifi-drivers) post to check is driver installed i have :

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/modprobe.d# modinfo rtl8821ae
modinfo: ERROR: Module rtl8821ae not found.
root@ubuntu:/etc/modprobe.d# find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless -name '*.ko'
find: ‘/lib/modules/5.0.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless’: No such file or directory
```

and form [this](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2044814) post:

```
root@ubuntu:~/rtlwifi_new#     sudo modprobe rtl8821ae
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8821ae not found in directory /lib/modules/5.0.0-23-generic
root@ubuntu:~/rtlwifi_new# dmesg | tail
\[ 2975.493281] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: fault 01 [WRITE] at 0000000000100000 engine 04 [BAR1] client 08 [HUB/HOST_CPU_NB] reason cc [] on channel -1 [007fce7000 unknown]
[ 2981.742904] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: fault 01 [WRITE] at 0000000000000000 engine 04 [BAR1] client 08 [HUB/HOST_CPU_NB] reason cc [] on channel -1 [007fce7000 unknown]
[ 2981.743002] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: fault 00 [READ] at 0000000000100000 engine 04 [BAR1] client 07 [HUB/HOST_CPU] reason 4c [] on channel -1 [007fce7000 unknown]
[ 2981.743029] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: DROPPED_MMU_FAULT 00000000
[ 2996.797871] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: fault 01 [WRITE] at 0000000000050000 engine 05 [BAR2] client 08 [HUB/HOST_CPU_NB] reason ca [] on channel -1 [007fd38000 unknown]
[ 2996.803470] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: fault 01 [WRITE] at 0000000000100000 engine 04 [BAR1] client 08 [HUB/HOST_CPU_NB] reason cc [] on channel -1 [007fce7000 unknown]
[ 3003.054698] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: fault 01 [WRITE] at 0000000000000000 engine 04 [BAR1] client 08 [HUB/HOST_CPU_NB] reason cc [] on channel -1 [007fce7000 unknown]
[ 3003.054924] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: fault 00 [READ] at 0000000000100000 engine 04 [BAR1] client 07 [HUB/HOST_CPU] reason 4c [] on channel -1 [007fce7000 unknown]
[ 3003.054966] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: DROPPED_MMU_FAULT 00000000
[ 3513.772212] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Thanks.

Comment: `rtlwifi_new` is unrelated. You're doing everything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problems with your kernel. It is half-installed.

Prpbably an unattended upgrade was going at the moment you powered off your system.

Boot with a previous kernel (Wi-Fi should work) and update the system.

BTW the Broadcom commands in the beggining of your question has no relateion to your problem, because you don't have a Broadcom device.

Comment: can i upgrade it via live USB Ubuntu, by some comand like `sudo chroot /mnt/`?

Comment: You can boot your system with a good kernel and upgrade it from there. That is much easier.

Comment: Dose doing this by live USB use less internet data?

Comment: There is no difference.