# Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 on iMac2009 failed - getting only an underscore with black screen

Tags: 20.04, bios

I am not able to get into the BIOS of the iMac to adjust either to reload older version of Ubuntu or to fix the graphics drivers.

I have tried all of the iMac commands to get into it.

What else can I try?

Comment: To fix incomplete update try this  https://askubuntu.com/q/1238355/968501 and to fix graphics drivers try this https://askubuntu.com/q/1232148/968501

Comment: These would work if I could get the computer to recognize the USB bootable drive

Comment: Looks like this is the way to go:   Steps :
1. Reset PRAM of your machine by holding option+command+P+R keys together soon after you press the Power button and hear the startup chime.
2. Hold the keys until the grey screen goes off completely (the machine should be restarting).
3. At "this" point, insert the Bootable USB Disk you created and press and hold the option key.
4. Hold the option key until you see the Startup Manager.

Hopefully your USB should be listed as one of the bootable disks in the Startup Manager.