# Ubuntu 20.04 not booting. How to recover it?

Tags: 20.04

My ubuntu 20.04 was working fine until today when I approved 971 MB update. It demanded restart which i did and then after selecting 'ubuntu' on grub menu, the manufacturer logo(MSI) is stuck.
No signs of ubuntu booting. I have a lot of Softwares installed for work purposes. I don't want to do a fresh reinstall.
Please suggest how I could recover ubuntu

I have nvidia rtx 2080 ti and I was using 460 nvidia driver

TIA

Comment: One assumes you have backups of your data? Sometimes recovery is easy, sometimes hard, sometimes impossible.

Comment: How did you install nVidia driver? If not from Ubuntu repository, you have to install it with every kernel update. Or only install nVidia driver from Ubuntu. Can you boot recovery mode?

Comment: @oldfred I updated my drivers using command line but system worked fine. its only after some system update that i can't boot it. I can boot recovery mode for all kernels and tried step here [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode] but to no avail. Please suggest how I could use live usb to recover ubuntu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with booting the system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163516/problems-with-booting-the-system)

Comment: @Raffa i tried your solution 2-3 times .. its still not booting. Any recommendations towards using live usb to recover ubuntu are welcome

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1232168) uses live USB.

Answer (score 2):

1. Immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up the GNU GRUB menu. (If you see the Ubuntu logo, you've missed the point where you can enter the GRUB menu.) With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GRUB menu. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GRUB screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> is unnecessary.

   The timing when to press the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key can be tricky, so sometimes if you miss it you need to try it again. If that doesn't work try the answers to [I can't get the GRUB menu to show up during boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/87409/).
2. From the first purple GNU GRUB screen select *Advanced options for Ubuntu* with the ↑ and ↓ keys and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You will then be prompted by a menu that looks something like this:

   [image]
3. Press the down arrow key until you select the **second entry from the top** (the one with the **recovery mode in the description**) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   Now you should see this recovery menu:

   [image: recovery menu]
4. Using the arrow keys scroll down to **network** (the third entry from the bottom in the Recovery Menu) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Using the arrow keys scroll down to **root** and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice.

   You should now see a root prompt, something like this:

   ```
    root@ubuntu:~#
   ```
6. At this stage you should have a read-only filesystem. You have to remount it with write permissions:

   ```
    mount -o rw,remount /
   ```
7. Uninstall the proprietary Nvidia graphics driver.

   ```
   apt update
   apt remove '^nvidia'
   apt autoremove  
   reboot
   ```

After rebooting Ubuntu 20.04 will be using the built-in open source nouveau graphics driver.

Comment: Since you have dropped to root's shell, I don't see the use of sudo-ing all commands.
In fact id does not work - refuses to act with sudo, while being root. Without sudo, works fine.

Comment: Tried, but my problem was not solved. Still does not start X server after reboot. Same symptoms.. But from root's shell I was able to run startx... :-o

Answer (score 0):

You can try booting an earlier version of the kernel. Try the following:

Start the computer and on the Grub menu select *Advanced options* > Select an earlier kernel version.

Also, you could try to update your MSI BIOS.

Comment: I tried those steps - I chose all kernel options i could from 'advanced ubuntu options'  but same story for everything. I also tried opening those kernels in recovery mode and repaired broken packages and tried to mount the filesystem as described [here][https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode] but to no avail. Is there anything I could do with a live usb to recover ubuntu ?

Comment: Also i have noticed that the kernel options show only 2 kernels now (after multiple hard restarts). It used to show 3 initially when the problem was fresh. the oldest one has vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Here i found the similar issue that my Linux OS was not booting instead a black screen with blinking underscore was visible.

So I tried the above solution and it worked.

The steps I followed.

Using the arrow keys scroll down to root and then press Enter twice.

You should now see a root prompt, something like this:

```
root@ubuntu:~#
```

At this stage you should have a read-only filesystem. You have to remount it with write permissions:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Uninstall the proprietary Nvidia graphics driver.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove '^nvidia'
sudo apt autoremove  
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Is this a Ubuntu OS answer?