# Unable to boot Ubuntu out of the blue

Tags: boot, drivers, dual-boot, nvidia

I was using my laptop just fine until I rebooted my device and saw an error message while booting.

Saying (`failed to allocate NvKmsKapiDevice Failed to register device`)

I think it's related to NVIDIA drivers. I tried to install drivers through recovery mode, but again got an error message. I think the error I am getting while installing the driver is perhaps because I am not connected to the internet, because I do not know how to connect to wifi in recovery mode.

I have an Asus ROG Strix g513 with Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 graphics card.
Ubuntu version - 20.04

Recommended driver - Nvidia driver 525 open.

Error while booting:

[image]

Error while installing drivers in recovery mode:

[image]

I am dual booting with Windows 11, and I can boot to the Windows without any issues.

Comment: Links to Google drive is a bad idea most people can not see them. This info needs to be part of the question. If they are text they should be cut and paste if you can not cut and paste use screen shots but include in the question. As well you need more info such as the version of Ubuntu, the video card and driver used and any other erros you see. Use the edit command and add this info to the question..

Comment: I added the things you mentioned @David

Comment: "I do not know how can I connect to wifi in recovery mode" is the first problem to solve.  I suggest googling for "ubuntu recovery mode wifi".

Comment: Can you boot into a live session? If so, run [GParted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted), take a screenshot of your hard disk and edit it into your question.

Comment: Follow instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1232168 … Except for installing `xserver-xorg` as you probably won’t  not need this one.

Comment: I currently do not have bootable usb, let me create one first @Raffles

Comment: @RonJohn I am trying to search it since a couple of hours but nothing is working, I tried connecting with ethernet connection, then enabled networking from recovery mode, but when I'm pinging on 8.8.8.8, its throwing (ping: connect: Network if unreachable)

Comment: @Raffa when I ran 'sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf' , its saying "cp: not writing through dangling symlink '/mnt/etc/resolv.conf' "

Comment: You probably changed `/etc/resolv.conf` on your original system earlier and broke the symlink ... It should be a symlink i.e. `/etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` .... Fix it, then `cp` should work.