# Ubuntu not booting after update and upgrade

Tags: reboot

My ubuntu 20.04.6 was working fine until today. I did update and upgrade from terminal and then I rebooted my workstation. It requested restart, which I did, and then after selecting 'ubuntu' on grub menu, it's booting up to certain extent and then there are no signs of Ubuntu booting.

I have a lot of software installed for work purposes. I don't want to do a fresh reinstall. Please suggest how I could recover Ubuntu.

I have Nvidia graphics.

The message I am getting is below

```
OK ] [OX 1 Mounted Mount unit for gtk2-common-thenes, revision 13.

[OX

1 Mounted Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, revision 1534. OK 1

Mounted Mount unit for core, revision 16091.

[ OK ] Mounted Mount unit for kde-francuorks-5-core18, revision 32. OK 1

Mounted Mount unit for gtk-common-thenes,

revision 1535.

[ OK ]

Mounted Mount unit for core22, revision 864.

COX 1

Reached target Mounted snaps.

OK Started GNOME Display Manager.... and deal with any system changes
```

Comment: If it's caused by NVIDIA driver, then you can remove it this way: https://askubuntu.com/a/1163539 or this other way: https://askubuntu.com/a/1232168 (*Don't do `apt install xserver-xorg`*) ... If, on the other hand, it's an incomplete upgrade, then you can fix it this way: https://askubuntu.com/a/1485452/968501

Comment: Try booting from a previous kernel from the grub/advanced menu. Try booting in a grub recovery mode.