# How to disable Nouveau kernel driver

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda, nouveau

When installing CUDA in Ubuntu 16.04 by executing cuda_8.0.44_linux.run,

I got the following error message in /var/log/nvidia-installer.log

[image]

Then I checked /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf and got

[image]

Any suggestion to disable Nouveau Kernel Driver?

I found [this 2012 discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112302/how-do-i-disable-the-nouveau-kernel-driver) but didn't work for me.

Comment: I did but didn't work.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

According to the [NVIDIA developer zone](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#pre-installation-actions): Create a file:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
```

With the following contents:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

Regenerate the kernel initramfs:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Finally, reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Read more at: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ixzz4rQODN0jy

Comment: This one worked perfectly, but i also had to remove the X0 lock files from /tmp.

Comment: It worked, thanks! BTW, in Arch Environment, the `update-initramfs -u` is different. You will need to find your kernel preset in `/etc/mkinitcpio.d/` (e.g. linux417.preset), and run `sudo mkinitcpio -p linux417`, and reboot. All done!

Comment: Works perfectly in Ubuntu 18.04.03. Thank you very much!

Comment: Didn't work on 18.04 for me, nvidia installer still complains about this nuveau.

Comment: Thx, it works on ubuntu server 20.04

Comment: FYI on Fedora, this worked for me!

(1) Downloaded the NVIDIA drivers/script for my video card. Executed it. It then generated files in `/usr/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf` and `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf` with the above contents. (2) Then, I had to run `dracut --regenerate-all -f` on Fedora as `sudo update-initramfs -u` does not work on Fedora. (3) Reboot and that's it!

Comment: Note: for anyone who is new to Linux and confused because some say `blacklist-nouveau.conf` meanwhile the other article says `nouveau-default.conf`, the answer is that the file name is not important. You can just name it with anything, as long as it's a `conf` file. The most important thing is you put it in `/etc/modprobe.d` directory

Answer (score 34):

maybe it is too late ,but hope can help for others. the follow tips worked for ubuntu 16.04 and elementary os 0.4.

1. remove all nvidia packages ,skip this if your system is fresh installed

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove nvidia* && sudo apt autoremove
   ```
2. install some packages for build kernel:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic
   ```
3. now block and disable nouveau kernel driver:

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   ```

Insert follow lines to the blacklist.conf:

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```

save and exit.

4. Disable the Kernel nouveau by typing the following commands(`nouveau-kms.conf` may not exist,it is ok):

   ```
   echo options nouveau modeset=0 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/nouveau-kms.conf
   ```
5. build the new kernel by:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
6. reboot

Comment: Is item 4 necessary? It looks to be a repeat of "options nouveau modeset=0" that was added to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf mentioned in your item 3.

Comment: I did this, then CTRL+ALT+F1, sudo service lightdm stop,then was able to run the installer. I don't know if it was essential to do this, but I did and I was able to run the installer successfully. Thanks!

Comment: This just killed my system. 

After rebooting now i see an endless blackscreen, not even a darn cursor ;(

Comment: Better change `sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` to `gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` :D

Comment: @revolutionary that's odd, you must not have a fallback driver. do you have a spare vga monitor anywhere??

Comment: @Tcll same here. My screen wont pass the Grub Bootloader. What to do now?

Comment: @revolutionary what did you do to fix it?

Comment: well, you can't undo your changes and rerun `sudo update-initramfs -u` to re-enable nouveau... I did just that like an idiot and had to reinstall xubuntu because I screwed everything up to where any nvidia driver installation failed. best thing I can recommend for @revolutionary is to grab a vga monitor (lcd, crt, doesn't matter). that should at least run off the fallback mode and help get you somewhere.

Comment: Luckily I'm installing on a GCloud Compute Virtual Instance, but I definitely think this answer hurt more than it helped.  Now I'm flooded with warnings like `WARNING: Unable to find a suitable destination to install 32-bit compatibility libraries. Your system may not be set up for 32-bit compatibility. 32-bit compatibility files will not be installed; if you wish to install them, re-run the installation and set a valid directory with the --compat32-libdir option.`  Downvote from me

Comment: @frank, sorry for that, the anwser may outdated, yes, you should down vote it

Comment: after following all the steps given from this method you can install Nvidia from the .run file which can be download from the Nvidia official site and follow the on screen instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the other answers, I assert that the `blacklist` keyword ***will not actually*** blacklist the driver.

Let me explain what that keyboard actually does. `blacklist` does not blacklist the driver at all. The most it can do is offer a gentle suggestion. What you are writing is not a rule, but rather a guideline for one small portion of the boot process. Ubuntu can decide to break your `blacklist` guidelines at any time. You can clearly see that `blacklist nouveau` does not actually what it claims to do, because you can still do `modprobe nouveau` with the guideline in place. Don't offer any `options` to `nouveau` for any ifs and buts, if `nouveau` is blocked like you want, it won't even get to see its options.

What you actually need is the `install [module] /bin/false` line:

1. `echo 'install nouveau /bin/false' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf`
2. `sudo update-initramfs -u`
3. `reboot`
4. `sudo modprobe nouveau` - Yes, please actually try this. You will instantly see the night and day difference that `install nouveau /bin/false` makes compared to the useless `blacklist nouveau`.

Comment: The only content in my blacklist-nouveau needs then to be 'install nouveau /bin/false' - is that correct?

Comment: @TheGlasses That is correct. That is the only thing you need, and you will know it's working when the `modprobe` output changes