# What to do when lspci and hwinfo freeze the system?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-geforce

What logs etc to post?

The computer is Clevo 650re with nVidia GeForce GTX 960M

Comment: I do not think these commands freeze the system.  Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Some people resolved this by blacklisting the nouveau driver. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=183185
https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/45825

Answer (score 3):

**1. Using lspci to get a list of devices**

To make lspci work temporarily, you have different possible options that might work :

- Check that everything is up-to-date, including non-free firmwares
- Disable ACPI : add acpi=off to the grub kernel command line (see [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/160056/803467))
- Blacklist some well-known drivers, like [nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/a/951892/803467)
- Install an older kernel

When you can run lspci, save the bus IDs in a file :

```
lspci | awk '{print $1}' > pci_ids.txt
```

**2. Debugging devices**

Then, reboot "normally", i.e. with the config where lspci was not working before, and run lspci with each id :

```
for i in `cat pci_ids.txt`; do echo " * CHECKING $i";lspci -s $i; done
```

Then, you will find which hardware is the source of the problem.

Comment: Worked great, thanks. For me, adding acpi=off to grub options was enough to get a working lspci. (NB: no need to make this permanent as explained in the last step of the linked solution). Then I found nvidia as the culprit and could investigate further