# CUDA or OpenCL on NVIDIA Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 17.04, bumblebee, cuda

I have installed `nvidia-375` drivers with `bumblebee` by following [this](http://lenovolinux.blogspot.com.au/2016/05/bumblebee-on-lenovo-t440p-nvidia-gt.html) guide.

However, there appears to be no way to get OpenCL or CUDA support running on this GPU with or without `optirun`/`primusrun`.

Is there any way to get OpenCL/CUDA without uninstalling `bumblebee`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

might be more simple to pull the source from nvidia, i did that a few months back for a crypto mining rig.

The general procedure

```
sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get purge --remove nvidia*
```

`wget` nvidia and cuda 
`chmod +x` both
`ctrl+alt+f1` to init1 
su to root

`sudo service lightdm stop` / `sudo service gdm stop` )

(cant recall if neveau blacklist required, the installer will let you know. If - may see [How to disable Nouveau kernel driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841876/how-to-disable-nouveau-kernel-driver))

`ctrl+alt+f3` to init3 if the installer wants network access

if the installer fails for some reason and you need to reboot, end up with black screen - hit ctrl+alt+f1 for init1 again and resume setup or uninstall the failed install with ./installer.run --uninstall.
`./`installer.run

```
nvidia-smi or `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version`
nvcc --version (or `-V` cant recall) altern `cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt`
```

Comment: Perhaps you could flesh this answer out with some more detail? I was unable to follow the instructions due to lack of links and normal CLI commands.