# Ubuntu 17.04 Nvidia 384 and Kernel Update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, kernel, 17.04

I recently got an Nvidia card, after long debating I convinced myself that I earned a little gaming - tho I only used the machine for webdev. so far I have no experience with gcards and ubuntu.

I installed the driver, or at least I tried. I got some problem with the nouveau kernel - so whatever stumbled upon this thread

[How to disable Nouveau kernel driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841876/how-to-disable-nouveau-kernel-driver)

Did whats posted on the accepted answer and now the pc won´t start.

I got 2 Kernels in the Advanced Menu (4.10.0-35 and 4.10.0-37) but in the root bash I also do not get any eth device to work, so no way of sudo apt-get update / upgrade.

Tomorrow I can get an USB Stick with 17.04 Live on it, any quick way to fix that with the Live Image? Recovery? Will it keep my files - I got an Backup, but not from my databases. So it would be nice to fix it.

Is there a log where I can figure out where the problem is?

Comment: You said that your PC won't boot. What do you mean? Are you having a login-loop (putting your password and instead of loading the desktop it's asking for password entry again)?

Comment: Sorry, I shoul´ve been more specific. It stops when loading "Starting user manager with UID ..." on the boot process

Comment: Please, if you can be more specific (as you said), edit your post and add more info. Do you have access to a root shell? Can you use apt-get update/upgrade/dist-upgrade? Do you have internet access? Can you boot on recovery mode kernel through "Advanced options"?

Comment: I answered 2/3 already in my initial post. No internet / I can access the root shell and I can use the Advanced options.

Comment: If you're on Wi-Fi, make a connection between your Computer and Router/Modem device via ethernet. Then, follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/92558/736783) guide in order to gain internet access via recovery-mode. Many users have solved the "Stuck on 'Starting user manager with UID'" problem by using apt-get update/upgrade/dist-upgrade. You can give it a try.

Comment: Using "Enable networking" does not work on both Kernel Versions. Is the Live USB Stick not an option?

Comment: I had it connected via ethernet btw.

Comment: I got it working by adding a DNS NS to /etc/resolv.conf (nameserver 8.8.8.8) - I can use update and upgrade now. We´ll see if it helps. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue.

There is a way to boot with Ubuntu "live CD" or "Live USB stick",
then select "Try Ubuntu".

When in, you can mount your "broken" system in terminal with:

> sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
>
> sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
>
> sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
>
> sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
>
> sudo chroot /mnt

now you can delete all the nvidia stuff and revert the blacklisting....