# What nvidia driver do i need for Gefroce 920M and how can i install it?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-geforce

I have installed ubuntu on my windows machine and now i want to install driver for it but i confused which nvidia driver to install. I have Nvidia GeForce 920M 4GB graphics card. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ubuntu-drivers package, it will install it for you.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-drivers-common
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices # this will show you information
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Make sure to blacklist nouveau driver if installs the nvidia package.

[How to disable Nouveau kernel driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841876/how-to-disable-nouveau-kernel-driver)

Answer (score 0):

We only have 2 options: generic or 3rd party. And the reason to install either has nothing to do with quality of the driver but if you want to keep your system FREE (as in not corrupted by drivers we/you can not visually check).

The generic one is installed by default. The 3rd party version you need to install yourself.

My advice: if the generic one works stick with that one.