# Ubuntu 22.04 blackscreen instead of log in

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 22.04, login

I am a newbie.
Installed Ubuntu 22.04.
after installation I got black screen instead of login screen
Read some and found out about NVIDIA drivers.
I have GEFORCE 920m.
I loaded Ubuntu, went to recovery mode, root, used "sudo apt purge nvidia*".
it worked out and I could login but every time I try to change graphic drivers to NVIDIA (recommended, any) I got black screen and could not login.
How can I install proper driver and should I have to install propietary ones?

Comment: Someone [asked this before](https://askubuntu.com/q/1005153/906933). Did you check it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nvidia Geforce GT 710 Driver Installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379138/nvidia-geforce-gt-710-driver-installation)

Comment: @kanehekili it did not work out

Comment: Well, thanks for your feedback. Since your not very verbose, I won't be able to help you. You could explain what you did and which errors occurred. I'm running a NVIDIA GEforce 770 with native drivers (470.182) from the repos with kernel 5.19 So it should work (on another distro with Kernel 6.1 same driver)

Comment: @kanehekili More details: Firstly I tried to install drivers via GUI. I've tried all proposed but after every try I got black screen. Then I tried your recommendations sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-drivers-common
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices # this will show you information
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall. It did not worked. Then I tried your recomendations + sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
With the following contents:
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
Regenerate the kernel initramfs:
sudo update-initramfs -u
Finally, reboot:
sudo reboot.

Comment: @kanehekili but after all I've got black screen. I do not know what to do. my sysytem Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, NVIDIA GEFORCE 920M, kernel 5.19.0-38

Comment: Usually we would appreciate, if you could share your information in your question. not in the comments. You can edit your question any time and add infos. The Nvidia   site confirms, that the 470 driver is the correct one. Since you can't login you could open a terminal with 'Crtl+Alt +F2'. Now login on the terminal and copy the output of `nvidia-smi` into your question. You'll have to make a picture though... The crucial info is **which version of the driver did you install**

Comment: @kanehekili thank you. think I have found the solution. I switched to Linux Mint. Works perfectly

Comment: Yup, it has an older Kernel. Makes  sense