# Installing Ubuntu in laptop with secondary (broken) Nvidia GPU disabled or blocked

Tags: drivers, nvidia, system-installation, amd-graphics, gpu

There are lots of similar threads, but no exact match of how to discard secondary GPU.

I have laptop with 3th gen. Intel core-7 processor that has HD Graphics in it. Also my laptop has Nvidia GPU that is broken and trying to use it causes complete lockdown in Windows and its hanging Ubuntu installation also.

Im trying to install Ubuntu Mate 18.04, but it hangs while installing, and Im almost certain the broken Nvidia GPU is the reason. Hanging happens right after setting up WIFI.

So my question is that how is it possible to install Ubuntu so that it only uses the Intel HD Graphics and not the secondary Nvidia GPU?

Comment: What model of laptop do you have ? It could be possible to turn off discrete nvidia graphics card in BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to disable discrete GPU on my laptop. However I managed to install Ubuntu, dont know exactly why it worked this time. I checked Expert mode in boot menu and somehow it installed fine.

After installation recovery boot worked, and blacklisting nouveau drivers did the trick. [How to disable Nouveau kernel driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841876/how-to-disable-nouveau-kernel-driver);