# Kern and Syslog full with the same error

Tags: kernel, 18.04, shutdown, nouveau, syslog

I get this error sometimes while shutting down, the screen goes full with this line:

```
AsimSafwan kernel: [ 2086.606655] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
```

The PC doesn’t shut down and instead runs the script of the above error, I have to force shut-down my PC.

Both the kernlog and Syslog are full with the same error. I recently deleted Kernlog1(8gb) and Syslog1(5gb). I was using 16.04 prior to this and it had no such issue. I began to face this problem after installing 18.04. The first time I installed 18.04, in a few days my root space (50 gb) was full because of the logs, I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 after formatting the root partition, but the problem persists.

- The graphics driver in use is: `nvidia-driver-390` (proprietary, tested).
- GNOME ver: 3.28.1

The output of the command `'lspci -nnk | awk -v n='[0300]' 'p&&/^\S/{p=0}!p{p=index($0,n)}p'` is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 [8086:1916] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] [1043:10de]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [1043:11c0]
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:9d2f] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [1043:201f]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [8086:9d31] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [1043:11c0]
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:15.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:9d60] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [1043:11c0]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 [8086:9d61] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [1043:11c0]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 [8086:9d3a] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI [1043:11c0]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:9d03] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1043:11c0]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port [8086:9d10] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:9d14] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 [8086:9d15] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9d48] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller [1043:11c0]
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC [8086:9d21] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP PMC [1043:11c0]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [1043:11c0]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [1043:11c0]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 930MX] [10de:134e] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM108M [GeForce 930MX] [1043:10de]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:1724]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

- I would like to add that I have selected Intel as the default GPU from NVIDIA X Server Settings.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | awk -v n='[0300]' 'p&&/^\S/{p=0}!p{p=index($0,n)}p'` to confirm the available graphics adapter(s) and driver(s) in use? Thanks.

Comment: @Wiking The output of your command is : `Kernel driver in use: i915`

Comment: @Wiking Output of `ubuntu-drivers devices`  is : `== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000134Esv00001043sd000010DEbc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM108M [GeForce 930MX]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `nouveau` driver used by your system. Pay your attention to string in log:  `Kernel driver in use: nouveau`.

Remove all of the Nvidia drivers first:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
```

Install recommended Nvidia driver afterwards:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
```

Reboot your computer:

```
sudo reboot
```

Finally follow [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841876/how-to-disable-nouveau-kernel-driver/951892#951892) to blacklist nouveau driver.