# New install Ubuntu 18.04 login unresponsive and loops

Tags: login

I just reinstalled ubuntu my desktop with 18.04. However, the login screen is not responsive at all. I've tested my mouse & keyboard on several other machines and they work just fine. Yet I can move the mouse all day on the desk top with 18.04 and it will barely move the cursor. It literally takes seconds if not a full minute for key presses to register if I just happen to get it to where I can enter my password. And if it does actually login, all it does is loop back to the original login screen. With patience, I can log into a command line prompt with alt+f3. That seems to work just fine.

I've tried several guides I found online to fix the issue. Many of them mention reinstalling lightdm, or checking the permissions on .XAuthority (I think that's the right file I saw, but I may be recalling incorrectly it's name). None of that seems to apply to me. lightdm is not installed and not available to be installed. /tmp has the right flags, there is no .XAuthority file. One thing I am noticing which I think is strange is that my home directory is suspiciously empty. This said... i've never actually logged in to the new installation before other than via command line. So it's possible this is normal. But the only thing that's there is the "examples.desktop" file. The folders Pictures, movies, etc.. have not been created yet.

I thought it might be a bad install or install disc, so I installed it on an old laptop and it works just fine. That's what I'm using right now. I tried reinstalling to the desk top multiple times (while trying to recreate the installation disc) and I've gotten the same result.

I'm not sure where to go from here so I could use some help. Thanks everyone!

**EDIT**
I borrowed an old monitor from a friend and switched to my older on chip video card. It looks like I can now login and everything looks like it's working ok. What's interesting is that the live CD worked fine with my more "modern" setup. I have 2 4k monitors attached to a NVIDIA video card. I'm not entirely positive on the model, but I think it's a G71. I'm trying to confirm that.

**EDIT #2**
I was able to get the newer monitors to connect to the older video card. They are running in basically 1080p and everything is working fine. So it's either issues with being in 4k or the video card. Which I assume it's more likely that there are issues with Ubuntu playing nice with the video card.

** EDIT #3**
After looking further, the video card is a 1030 2GH LP OC NVIDIA card

Answer (score 1):

To others stuck in a similar spot—what solved the login loop after fresh install issue on my machine was installing the latest Nvidia drivers from the terminal, then rebooting.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend that you **[edit]** this to expand it with information about how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple days of digging around and trying to find answers, what seems to have resolved my issue was to disable the nouveau kernal driver. I found this on ask ubuntu:

[How to disable Nouveau kernel driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841876/how-to-disable-nouveau-kernel-driver)