# Ubuntu login loop reappears after every reboot, how to fix it?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, login

I tried everything [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) but nothing helped. What I found helped is to reinstall manually the proprietary nvidia driver(NVIDIA-Linux-x86_63-390.87.run). But only until the next restart. After that I am stuck again in a login loop and have to reinstall the drivers again. This is cumbersome and I would like a fix where I do not have to reinstall them every time.
The problem seems to be that both the nvidia driver and the nouveau driver want control over something(xorg server, gpu, display)?
I found this out because of this [post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2328508&page=2). Specifically after running `lspci -vk | grep -iA15 NVIDIA` I get the line:

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960] (rev a2)
        ....
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

This seems odd to me becaue of two things. I know I saw once somewhere a file that was created by the nvidia driver that read something along this:

```
# Nvidia driver autogenerated do not touch
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

Plus I followed this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841876/how-to-disable-nouveau-kernel-driver) and added a file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf with this content:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

and then I did:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```

but the lspci line still shows the same drivers, notably nouveau being still there and the /var/log/xorg.0.log shows:

```
(II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
....
(II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
....
(EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -2
(WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
```

**Summary**

- How to fix the login loop without needing to reinstall the nvidia driver manually every time?
- How to blacklist the nouveau driver?

**What are not options**

- Reinstalling ubuntu is not an option.
- Just using the nouvea drivers. I need the nvidia drivers.

Let me know if you need more info, e.g. the .xsession-error log.

Comment: You're using `blacklist nouvea` but the driver is called `nouveau`

Comment: That was a typo in the post not in the file

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with the first answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762831/ubuntu-16-stuck-in-login-loop-after-installing-nvidia-364-drivers). This simply installed the nvidia 410.73 driver. Don't know why this works and the 390 didn't so I will leave this open in case somebody has a hint how I could get it working with the 390 driver.