# Ubuntu 18.04 Dark Screen After Disabling Nouveau Driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, graphics, nouveau

I wanted to update Nvidia driver and install cuDNN on my computer and the official guide recommends disabling nouveau driver, so I followed this guide: [How to disable Nouveau kernel driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841876/how-to-disable-nouveau-kernel-driver).  I thought this shouldn't be a problem given that I already have Nvidia driver installed and running on my computer.

However, after doing exactly what this post said, I cannot boot desktop anymore (screen goes dark before password screen).

What did I do wrong?  Is there a way for me to revert back to before I changed the config files?  What should I do instead to safely disable nouveau?  Thank you!

Comment: Try adding "modprobe.blacklist=nouveau nvidia-drm.modeset=1" to the kernel command line and boot