# How do you install CUDA 11 on Ubuntu 20.10 and verify the installation

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, 20.10

There seem be be several options to install CUDA on Ubuntu 20.10: It is pre-bundled with 20.10, there are various installers at the [official NVIDIA page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=2004&target_type=runfilelocal), etc.

**Question:** What is a recommended way to install CUDA 11.X on Ubuntu 20.10, and how do I *verify* the installation?

Answer (score 29):

**Install the NVIDIA driver**

This might be an optional step, but it is always good to first remove potential previously installed NVIDIA drivers:

```
sudo apt-get purge *nvidia*
sudo apt autoremove
```

Next, let's install the latest driver:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455
```

After this, we need to **restart** the computer to finalize the driver installation.
Next we can verify whether the drive was succesfully installed:

```
nvidia-smi
```

This should contain the following or similar:

> NVIDIA-SMI 455.28       Driver Version: 455.28

**Install CUDA Toolkit**

Next we can install the CUDA toolkit:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

We also need to set the CUDA_PATH. Add this

```
export CUDA_PATH=/usr
```

at the end of your `.bashrc` and run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now your CUDA installation should be complete, and

```
nvidia-smi
```

should indicate that you have CUDA 11.1 installed.

**Test the CUDA toolkit installation /configuration**

One of the best way to verify whether CUDA is properly installed is using the official "CUDA-sample". Ubuntu does not package them as part of "nvidia-cuda-toolkit" but we can download them directly from NVIDIA's github page:

```
wget https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/archive/v11.1.tar.gz
tar xvf v11.1.tar.gz 
cd cuda-samples-11.1
```

For whatever reason, NVIDIA did not chose to include a modern build system (e.g. cmake), but ships a plain old Makefile instead. If just running "make" does not work for you, carefully read the error messages and see whether e.g. some required dependencies are not installed.

In order to help the build process a little, it might be advisable to specify the compute architecture of your GPU.

1. You can find out your GPU by running `nvidia-smi`. Mine is a Quadro RTX 3000.
2. Next google your GPU to find out the corresponding compute architecture. For the Quadro RTX 3000, it is "turing", version 7.5.
3. Specify the architecture version when running make, e.g.

```
make SMS="75"
```

If the compilation was succesful, you can try out one of the samples. For instance:

```
./bin/x86_64/linux/release/immaTensorCoreGemm
```

You should see the following or similar output:

```
M: 4096 (16 x 256)
N: 4096 (16 x 256)
K: 4096 (16 x 256)
Preparing data for GPU...
Required shared memory size: 64 Kb
Computing... using high performance kernel compute_gemm_imma 
Time: 6.030176 ms
TOPS: 22.79
```

Comment: This all is great, but the first command (`sudo apt purge *nvidia*`) will fail. Use `apt-get` instead.

Comment: Thanks, corrected.

Comment: You might want to quote the "\*nvidia\*" so any files in your current working directory with "nvidia" in their names do not mess up the command.

Comment: libcuda is not installed errors on make SMS="61"

Comment: This installs nvcc of a lower version than the rest of the installation. This is not without problems, e.g. https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/issues/57 where the older nvcc can't compile the newer (v11.2) code.

Comment: I hit the same issue as @GiorgosSfikas - it looks like cuda v11.0 is in the ubuntu repos for 20.10, so I just downloaded the matching sample code to make it work. People should also check `nvcc -V` for the appropriate version.

Comment: How do you check the architecture version? My GPU is a GeForce GTX 980, Maxwell architecture, but I seem to be unable to find the version to call `make SMS="XX"`

Comment: sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit installs cuda 10.1 on Ubuntu 20.04. Not Cuda 11

Answer (score 11):

since all of the explanations i found so far were not satisfying, here are the steps i came up with to install the latest nvidia driver (465) with cuda `11.3`

first you have to uninstall all cuda and nvidia related drivers and packages

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get purge cuda*
sudo apt autoremove
```

then

```
reboot
```

then (if not already done) disable nouveau as described here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/951892/634048 and `reboot` again

download cuda and install.

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.3.1/local_installers/cuda_11.3.1_465.19.01_linux.run
sudo sh cuda_11.3.1_465.19.01_linux.run
```

Follow the post-installation instructions found on the [CUDA Toolkit Installation Guide for Linux](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions). This involves updating the PATH and environment variables:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.3/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.3/lib64\
                 ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

**IMPORTANT** if you need 32bit support - there are several applications only running with 32-bit drivers (like steam)

**opt out** of installation of nvidia drivers for cuda installation and install drivers from here:
https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/171980/en-us
also check if driver is compatible for your model! (in general that should be the case)

```
sudo sh 'NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-465.19.01.run'
```

and **opt in for 32-bit support** when asked

done

*I did NOT test it for any other versions than `20.04`, but it should work for `18.04` to `21.04`*

Comment: Thanks for the input, it works well!
However 11.4 version is out already, so would be good to remove version-specific advice from your post. And there are some more install methods except runfile, which could be found here
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads.

Also adding export variables to ~/.bashrc prevents them from being lost upon reboot

Comment: As of August 2021, version 470 does not work reliably on Ubuntu (by my own experience), so I think the 465 recommendation is appropriate.  Here's a link to install instructions for all versions in case people need to downgrade:  https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive

Comment: Awesome thanks man ! 
This worked for me but removing my existing nvidia display drivers install meant that my second monitor stopped displaying signal. and I had to do the additional steps 

make sure nvidia-prime is installed (`sudo apt install nvidia-prime`)
switch to nvidia (`sudo prime-select nvidia`)
remove stray blacklist files (`sudo rm /lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf`)
update the initrd (`sudo update-initramfs -u`)
`reboot`

Context: Laptop with dual integrated AMD and dedicated Nvidia, connected Nvidia directly to external monitor.

Comment: I was having trouble installing `cuda 11.3` which turned out to be outdated version for my kernel `5.13.0-40-generic`. I had to downgrade my kernel to `5.8.18`. You can find the compatibility of kernel and cuda in system-requirement section here https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.3.1/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html

Comment: In the last, don't forget to remove the latest kernel

Comment: I like that this works if you want a specific version of cuda - you can go to the nvidia website, and look for runfile (local) of the version you want, and you're good to go (e.g. https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-7-0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=18.04&target_type=runfile_local) . Most guides only work for the latest version of cuda. That said, this also horked my screen resolution after step 1. :P