# Nvidia driver install Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia

I have the following message currently on screen after accepting the licence

```
The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  
Are you sure you want to continue?
```

Is it safe to proceed? What does this mean?

Comment: How did you get that error? Did you install the Nvidia driver via the nvidia.com site or did you follow this guide http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Comment: I downloaded to .run file from nvidia.com, disabled x server and ran .run as root. I did not see that guide before. I will follow it and update. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Fixed: Exited the install, disabled noveau by following an answer on this post (added blacklists to file) rebooted system, restarted installation and ignored the initial warning this time. Drivers and card now working.

[How do I disable the "Nouveau Kernel Driver"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112302/how-do-i-disable-the-nouveau-kernel-driver)

Comment: I was never good at installing drivers. As I tried updating the thing got ` Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915` Love the cycling though.

Answer (score 3):

Please try the deb (local) of CUDA 8.0 toolkit. You don't have to install the driver using *.run file, thereby avoiding the issue with Nouveau (enable/disable).

I was stuck with this issue for a long time for my Ubuntu 16.04. After installing a fresh copy of Ubuntu 16.04, I installed CUDA 8.0 toolkit using the deb (local):

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

Nvidia driver is working well on my computer now. Prior to that, I was trying to install Nvidia driver using the *.run file without any luck. Give it a shot it will save your valuable time.

Comment: how did you got this to work?
`$ sudo apt-get install cuda
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-1-local-10.1.105-418.39 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

Comment: Thank you so much, you save my day!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the roadblock was a file named `/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install` which was intentionally left there to prevent Nvidia install from overwriting Ubuntu native installs.  I removed the file and the error did not recur.