# Flickering behavior on Ubuntu 16.04 with AMD Ryzen 5 1600 + GTX1050 graphics card

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, nvidia-geforce

I beg for help. Please have a look on [this](https://youtu.be/DJwl9O4RAW4) video to see my problem. You'll see that my screen flickers when I move the pointer to a link (indeed I was looking for help on askubuntu).

I don't understand this bug and I do not even know what it correlates with. Sometimes it is a new page (with a lot of brightness), but this time it's just pointing to something!

I have a AMD Ryzen 5 1600 with a GTX1050 graphics card, and a LG monitor connected with a VGA to HDMI adapter since there is no integrated graphics card in my system. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and Nvidia drivers version 384.130. It improved for a few days after Nvidia drivers installation, but now it is worse. What could it be?

It is possible that somebody else have asked before, but I'm not an expert user of Ubuntu, so I don't even know what to look for. I really hate Windows, so for the sake of humanity please help me with my transition!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112302/how-do-i-disable-the-nouveau-kernel-driver) I made:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-390 nvidia-modprobe
```

Blacklist nouveau

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
```

Wrote:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

Then

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```

And all is working perfectly.